# how to make google custom search white background transparent?

Tags: html, google-custom-search

this is my code so far. i want to make white edge(background) transparent. `background-color:transparent !important;` does not work. please help. thanks

```
<style>
.container {
position: relative; 
width: 49%;
top: -11px;
float: right;
background-color:transparent !important;
}
</style>
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=xxxxxxhidenxxxxxxxxx"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="gcse-search">
</div>
</div>
```

output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnPB9.jpg)

Edited 1: just realized that white edge is from padding 13. please help me on how to remove padding 13 based on my code. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved, complete code below:

```
<style type="text/css">
.googlesearch {
position: relative; 
width: 40%;
float: right;
top: 4px;
margin-right: 5px;
}
.cse .gsc-control-cse, 
.gsc-control-cse {
padding: 0em;
background: transparent;
border: 0px;
}
</style>
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx></script>
<div class="googlesearch">
    <div class="gcse-search"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the css directly to the cse elements. The cse script will just create a div inside the same parent element with id similar or equal to `"___gcse_0"`. Check the generated html. I haven't tried this myself, but a css rule on `.gsc-control-cse` instead of `.container` should work. Otherwise, you'll just have to dig through with developer tools to figure out what element has the white background.